# Disable XUL cache in Thunderbird 60

Tags: thunderbird-addon

In previous Thunderbird version (52) i disable XUL cache `via about:config` settings `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache=TRUE`. In Thunderbird 60 this option not working and i have to reinstall addon to see the changes. How to see the changes during the development of the plugin without reinstalling in Thunderbird 60?